# Something going wrong with drawBitmap - with source and dest rectangles

Tags: android

I have a game in which, during one of the levels, sheep can get blown up by mines. The explosion animation is controlled by having a png containing a 4x4 array of explosion images within a 512x515 png file... see below.

[image]

I then animate the explosion using the following code:

```
            exp_bitmap_number_to_draw = (int)(time_since_death / 100);

            if (exp_bitmap_number_to_draw < 16)
            {
                explosion_dst_rect.left = b2sx(sheep_x[i]) - sheep_radius * 5;
                explosion_dst_rect.right = b2sx(sheep_x[i]) + sheep_radius * 5;

                explosion_dst_rect.bottom = b2sy(sheep_y[i]) + sheep_radius * 5;
                explosion_dst_rect.top = b2sy(sheep_y[i]) - sheep_radius * 5;

                explosion_src_rect.left = 128 * (exp_bitmap_number_to_draw % 4);
                explosion_src_rect.top = 128 * (exp_bitmap_number_to_draw / 4);

                explosion_src_rect.right = explosion_src_rect.left + 128;
                explosion_src_rect.bottom = explosion_src_rect.top + 128;

                canvas.drawBitmap(explosion_bitmap, explosion_src_rect, explosion_dst_rect, null);
            }
```

Where explosion_src_rect is a Rect and explosion_dst_rect is a RectF. b2sx() and b2sy() are functions which convert from the absolute coordinates on the sheep on the "playing field" to the coordinates on the screen - its simply adding an offset.

The code works perfectly on several phones I've tried, including a nexus S and a Galaxy S II. But just now a friend tried the code on a samsung galaxy tab 8.9 and found the explosions appeared goofey. He sent me this partial screen grab:

[image]

Any idea what could be causing this?

Comment: Are you using a different bitmap for the bigger screen? also, how is sheep_radius defined?

Comment: There are only one set of bitmaps. They are used for all screen sizes. float sheep_radius is the canvas width divided by 40.

Comment: if you use only one set of bitmaps for all screens you should place it into res/drawable-nodpi folder. Then android won't resize your bitmaps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If resources are not available in the correct density, the system loads the default resources and scales them up or down as needed to match the current screen's density.
There are some situations in which you might not want Android to pre-scale a resource. The easiest way to avoid pre-scaling is to put the resource in a resource directory with the `nodpi` configuration qualifier. For example:
`res/drawable-nodpi/icon.png`. So you have to put your bitmaps into `` `res/drawable-nodpi/ `` folder.
Have a look at: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: I think the problem here is that however he's loading the file, Android isn't pre-scaling the bitmap - making the part of the screen being drawn to bigger than the chunk of the bitmap he needs - Still a good comment on the nodpi folder, though

Comment: Once I have similar problem. I put all bitmaps into res/drawable folder and used coefficients to scale my bitmaps, so when I tested my game on the different screens drawing went wrong. The size of bitmaps was bigger then I thought. After some digging I put it into nodpi and it became cool!

Answer (score 0):

the width of your destination rectangle, instead of being the size of one of your explosion frames, as you said, is being set to the width of the canvas / 4.  Phones are typically of similar size, but the larger tablet has a much larger screen size - As it says in the documentation:

> Draw the specified bitmap, scaling/translating automatically to fill the destination rectangle [...]
>   This function ignores the density associated with the bitmap. This is because the source and destination rectangle coordinate spaces are in their respective densities, so must already have the appropriate scaling factor applied.

So your bitmap, not scaled to the canvas size, is getting drawn starting with the src Rect, but expands beyond the bounds of the src because it's been told to fill the DST, ignoring the densities of the two locations.

As to solution, I'm not sure, exactly - would probably be better to just have images of all sizes raring to go in your `/res`.  Depending on how you load the bitmap, you might be able to get the bitmap to scale, but then your fixed width translation across the bitmap would have to become more dynamic.

Hope that helps somehow :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem which I asked on here and the answer for me was to load my bitmaps like this, rather than the normal way:

getResources().openRawResource(imageId)