# Android - Radio Group Button Text Position

Tags: android, android-layout, radio-group

I have a layout which have RadioGroup and radiobuttons. it works but there are problems in display. I've shared the screenshots below.

Android 4.2.1  - 4.65 inch
[image: Android 4.2.1 - 4.65 inch]

Tablet Android 2.2  -  7 inch
[image: Tablet Android 2.2 - 7 inch]

Android 4.1.2  - 5.5 inch
[image: Android 4.1.2 - 5.5 inch]

**code from the bottorbar layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="3dp" android:gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/bottom"
     >

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioTur"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:measureWithLargestChild="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/rad_anasayfa"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:button="@null"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/anasayfabutton"
    android:textColor="@color/White"
    android:onClick="Anasayfa_TIKLA"
    android:text="Anasayfa" >
    </RadioButton>

      <RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/rad_haber"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:button="@null"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/haberlerbutton"
    android:textColor="@color/White"
    android:onClick="Haber_TIKLA"
    android:text="Haberler" >
    </RadioButton>

        <RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/rad_duyuru"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:button="@null"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/duyurubutton"
    android:textColor="@color/White"
    android:onClick="Duyuru_TIKLA"
    android:text="Duyurular" >
    </RadioButton>

          <RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/rad_yemek"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:button="@null"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/yemekbutton"  
    android:textColor="@color/White"
    android:onClick="Yemek_TIKLA"
    android:text="Yemek" >
    </RadioButton>

            <RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/rad_search"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:button="@null"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:onClick="Arama_TIKLA"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/search_icon"
    android:textColor="@color/White"
    android:text="Arama" >
    </RadioButton>

</RadioGroup>
</LinearLayout>
```

**code from main layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
     android:id="@+id/AnaLayout"
     >
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" >

    <include
        android:id="@+id/cell1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        layout="@layout/bottombar"
         />
</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I have been working for a few days.I didn't understand problem. Can someone help me ?

[image: my icon]
my icon

Comment: use android:layout_width="wrap_content" for RadioButtons.

Comment: thanks for quick comment but it not working .

Comment: place the radio group in the horizontall scrollview and it will work'

Comment: possible duplicate of [Flexible android layout for multiple screen sizes/densities](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4670002/flexible-android-layout-for-multiple-screen-sizes-densities)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found problem. The Problem is `android:button="@null"`.

If the `RadioButton` has the `android:button="@null"` property the result will be:
[image]

If the `RadioButton` doesn't have the `android:button="@null"` property the result will be:
[image]

If the `RadioButton` has the `android:button="@null"` and `android:background="@android:color/transparent"` properties the result will be:
[image]

I added the `android:background="@android:color/transparent"` property to all `RadioButton`s and the problem was resolved.

Comment: when i'm setting android:button="@null" , the radio button is not getting checked(clicked). Im i doing something wrong. please help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28052820/android-custom-radio-button-not-getting-checked

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

Change the `RadioGroup` **width** as `match_parent` and try.

```
<RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioTur"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:measureWithLargestChild="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
```

and

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" >

    <include
        android:id="@+id/cell1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        layout="@layout/bottombar"
         />
</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Here is my full code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="3dp" >

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioTur"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:measureWithLargestChild="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rad_anasayfa"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:button="@null"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/uP13v"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:onClick="Anasayfa_TIKLA"
            android:text="Anasayfa"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" >
        </RadioButton>

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rad_haber"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:button="@null"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/uP13v"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:onClick="Haber_TIKLA"
            android:text="Haberler"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" >
        </RadioButton>

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rad_duyuru"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:button="@null"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/uP13v"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:onClick="Duyuru_TIKLA"
            android:text="Duyurular"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" >
        </RadioButton>

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rad_yemek"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:button="@null"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/uP13v"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:onClick="Yemek_TIKLA"
            android:text="Yemek"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" >
        </RadioButton>

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rad_search"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:button="@null"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/uP13v"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:onClick="Arama_TIKLA"
            android:text="Arama"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" >
        </RadioButton>
    </RadioGroup>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: thanks last child's text problem is solved. But others not changed.

Comment: @CanerBalım change `RadioButton` width as `android:layout_width="0dp"` and also add `android:singleLine="true"`

Comment: thanks . Multiline is gone but texts look like this

 Ana...  Hab... Duy... Yem... Arama

Comment: @CanerBalım Chaeck my edit also. change the textsize as `android:textSize="18dp"`

Comment: @CanerBalım after changing textsize it displaying like that.

Comment: if I change text size 9sp its works but is not recommended ( Avoid using sizes smaller than 12sp: 9sp )

Comment: yes images are good but it seems there is space at the left side 2nd image (Tablet Android 2.2 - 7 inch) .

Comment: @CanerBalım remove `android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"` and try

Comment: @CanerBalım it's impossible. it's working perfectly.

Comment: I think so but it seems there is space at the left side. below android 4.2

Comment: @CanerBalım can you upload only one `drawableTop` image .

Comment: first remove `padding` in elements and in parent and then check. Radiobuttons should be with width wrap_parent. Do the same with height. Every radioobutton could have `layout_gravity` centered to `center`. Singleline is not the solution here...

Comment: if i remove singleline its look like (Tablet Android 2.2 - 7 inch) image.

Comment: @CanerBalım see my edit i am getting all size of devices like that only.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I didnt understand but I opened new project and put your code and icons. But result is still the same.

Answer (score 0):

Try out below layout. 
I have assigned an equal weight to all the RadioButton's so that it will be adjust its size according to the screen size. 
Its working fine now. Change your images accroding to you.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/aa"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="3dp"
    android:weightSum="1" >

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioTur"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rad_anasayfa"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".2"
            android:button="@null"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_circle"
            android:onClick="Anasayfa_TIKLA"
            android:text="Anasayfa"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" >
        </RadioButton>

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rad_haber"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".2"
            android:button="@null"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_circle"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:onClick="Haber_TIKLA"
            android:text="Haberler"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" >
        </RadioButton>

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rad_duyuru"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".2"
            android:button="@null"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_circle"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:onClick="Duyuru_TIKLA"
            android:text="Duyurular"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" >
        </RadioButton>

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rad_yemek"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".2"
            android:button="@null"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_circle"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:onClick="Yemek_TIKLA"
            android:text="Yemek"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" >
        </RadioButton>

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rad_search"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".2"
            android:button="@null"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_circle"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:onClick="Arama_TIKLA"
            android:text="Arama"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" >
        </RadioButton>
    </RadioGroup>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks but not working . it seems like 2nd image. but last childs text improved.

Comment: In my side its looking perfect. @CanerBalım Add the line `android:gravity="center"` in your first `RadioButton` and check.

Comment: thanks but is not working android 2.2 tablet.  why did you add radioGroup-text and  radioGroup-android:drawableTop property ?

Comment: Its just for viewing puporse nothing else. Can you show me your screenshot ? @CanerBalım

Comment: thanks for help . Your codes view look like 2nd image. but last child text is improved.

Comment: What is the problem with 2nd image ?

Comment: problem is left space and text.

Comment: Make sure your 2nd image size is same as other image size.